# ¿Como puedo agregar fecha de nacimiento a mi proyecto usando método DATIME?

Tags: c#

Mi programa pide el nombre, apellido, documento, y fecha de nacimiento para agregar a un objeto alumno a la lista y no se como agregarla con ese método datime aqui les dejo mi código desde ya gracias

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace abm
{
    class Program

    {


        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            List<Alumno> Alumnolista = new List<Alumno>();
            Console.WriteLine("bienvenido, elija una opción " + "\n");
            int opcion = 0;
            Console.Write("1º) Alta" + "\n" + "2º) Baja" + "\n" + "3º) Modificar" + "\n" + "4º) Consultar" + "\n");

            do
            {

                string entrykey = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!int.TryParse(entrykey, out opcion))
                {
                    opcion = 0;
                }

                switch (opcion)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("Alta..");


                        Alumno objalumno;
                        objalumno = new Alumno();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del alumno");
                        objalumno.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Apellido del alumno");
                        objalumno.Apellido = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Documento del Alumno");
                        objalumno.Documento = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Alumnolista.Add(objalumno);
                        Console.WriteLine("Alumno registrado");
                        Console.ReadKey();

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Write("Baja..");


                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.Write("Modificar..");
                        // Continuar lógica y extraer métodos //
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.Write("Consultar..");
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del Alumno que desea buscar");

                        foreach (Alumno a in Alumnolista)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(a.inscripción());
                            break;
                        }
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        // Continuar lógica y extraer métodos //
                        break;

                }
                Console.ReadKey();


            } while (opcion != 5);


        }
    }
```

y la clase

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace abm
{
    public class Alumno
    {
        public string Nombre
        { get; set; }
        public string Apellido
        { get; set; }
        public int Documento
        { get; set; }
        public string Nombrebusc
        { get; set; }





        public string inscripción()
        {
            return "El Alumno" + this.Nombre + this.Apellido + "El Alumno fue inscripto : " ;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: por favor no uses mayúsculas en tu título, equivale a gritar

Comment: Muy buenas Facundo, cuando dices "metodo datime" te refieres a usar un objeto `DateTime` para guardar la fecha? Un saludo

Comment: me refiero usar el metodo data time para que en consola me pida la fecha de nacimiento del objeto alumno que agrego a un lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

entiendo que te refieres a la clase `DateTime`. Simplemente añade una propiedad a tu clase `Alumno` de tipo `DateTime` y cuando la pidas al usuario haz un `Parse` o un `TryParse` ([aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467613/parse-v-tryparse) te dejo un enlace con más información sobre ambos métodos) de la fecha obtenida por consola.

**Alumno.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace abm
{
    class Alumno
    {
        public string Nombre
        { get; set; }
        public string Apellido
        { get; set; }
        public int Documento
        { get; set; }
        public string Nombrebusc
        { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaNacimiento
        { get; set; }


        public string inscripción()
        {
            return "El Alumno" + this.Nombre + this.Apellido + "El Alumno fue inscripto : ";
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace abm
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Alumno> Alumnolista = new List<Alumno>();
            Console.WriteLine("bienvenido, elija una opción " + "\n");
            int opcion = 0;
            Console.Write("1º) Alta" + "\n" + "2º) Baja" + "\n" + "3º) Modificar" + "\n" + "4º) Consultar" + "\n");

            do
            {

                string entrykey = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!int.TryParse(entrykey, out opcion))
                {
                    opcion = 0;
                }

                switch (opcion)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("Alta..");


                        Alumno objalumno;
                        objalumno = new Alumno();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del alumno");
                        objalumno.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Apellido del alumno");
                        objalumno.Apellido = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Documento del Alumno");
                        try
                        {
                            objalumno.Documento = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("El documento debe ser un entero");
                            //Tratar excepción como se desee (salir, añadir documento por defecto o lo que quieras hacer)
                        }

                        Alumnolista.Add(objalumno);
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento con formato (dd/mm/yyyy)");
                        try
                        {
                            objalumno.FechaNacimiento = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("La fecha debe tener el formato (dd/mm/yyyy)");
                            //Tratar excepción como se desee (salir, añadir fecha por defecto o lo que quieras hacer)
                        }

                        Alumnolista.Add(objalumno);
                        Console.WriteLine("Alumno registrado");
                        Console.ReadKey();

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Write("Baja..");


                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.Write("Modificar..");
                        // Continuar lógica y extraer métodos //
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.Write("Consultar..");
                        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del Alumno que desea buscar");

                        foreach (Alumno a in Alumnolista)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(a.inscripción());
                            break;
                        }
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        // Continuar lógica y extraer métodos //
                        break;

                }
                Console.ReadKey();


            } while (opcion != 5);
        }
    }
}
```

Como ejemplo, he añadido un par de `try/catch` para el control y tratamiento de excepciones en caso de que introduzcan mal el formato. No sé si has llegado a ver eso. Te dejo un enlace [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/).